# extends Application in Maven not working

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

[image]

I have a case extends application dependency with Netbeans, but dependency no items. Why?

Comment: Why are you extending Application?
1) In Spring boot you don't have to extend your main application from any class.

2) The error is due to the fact that you don't have Application class in your path. Just dont extend Application or reference it in any way.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your post. Regarding your problem, I suggest you to follow the official [Spring Boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

Comment: thanks, but I want to create a JavaFX application and in the tutorial I see he can extends the maven's 'Application' and working dependencies

Comment: but I want to create a JavaFX application and in the tutorial I see he can extends the maven's 'Application' and working dependencies